# Overlay edge between two tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to have two nodes in Tikz, filled with text. Then I want an edge from one position in the first node to another position in the second node:

[image: What I want]

This is what I tried: Inside the tikz nodes text, I use another nested tikzpicture with `remember picture`, where I define coordinates, which should later be reusable as edge start end end points. (Here I used filled nodes instead for debugging)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Tikz Test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw node [text width=60mm,fill=black!5] (n1) {Multi\\line \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]\node[fill=black,text width=2mm](start){};\end{tikzpicture} \\text};
        \draw node [text width=60mm,fill=black!5,below=of n1] {Another\\multi\\line \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]\node[fill=black,text width=2mm](end){};\end{tikzpicture}\\text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw (start) -- (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image: What I get]

The nodes (black rectangles) are where they should be, but the edge connecting them is never where I want it to be. I tried multiple variations, (trying different places where I define the edge, and whether I use the `overlay` attribute or not), but neither version yields the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `remember picture` for the `tikzpicture` connecting the nodes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Tikz Test}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\draw node [text width=60mm,fill=black!5] (n1) 
  {Multi\\line \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[fill=black,text width=2mm](start){};\end{tikzpicture} \\text};
\draw node [text width=60mm,fill=black!5,below=of n1] {Another\\multi\\line \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]\node[fill=black,text width=2mm](end){};\end{tikzpicture}\\text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw (start) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, is best not to nest `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: I thought `remember picture` was used if you want to define coordinates (or nodes) which you want to reuse later. So why do I need it for the edge connecting the two previously defined nodes?

Comment: @Misch You need to add the `remember picture` option to all pictures that contain nodes that you wish to
reference and also to all pictures from which you wish to reference a node in another picture.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. Additionally I just found a better way to prevent nested tikzpictures: `subnode`s

Comment: For some reason I can get this to work with `pdflatex`, but not with `latex`.  With the latter the two boxes are not connected and a small segment is drawn in the middle of the page.